# Login failed for user 'IFC\WIN5062$'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get this Login failed for user error.  Here is my code now in the web.config file:

```
<add name= "Product" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5011.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B2856_Product;User Id=#######;Password:****** "/>
<add name="ProductEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Product.csdl|res://*/Models.Product.ssdl|res://*/Models.Product.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL5011.Smarterasp.net;attachdbfilename=DB_9B2856_Product;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="EmailmeContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=EmailmeContext-20140604141117; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EmailmeContext-20140604141117.mdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

with the ####### and the ****** actually matching a user id and password I have set up that will actually open the database when I login into SmarterAsp.net but when I run the file I get the above error.

Comment: So your SQL Server is configured for SQL Auth and you are passing it a valid SQL User Name and Password (not NT User info)? Correct? Can you login to SSMS using SQL Auth and the same User and password?

Comment: I uploaded my database to SmarterAsp.Net.  I put a user id and password on the database I can login into the database when I'm logged into SmarterAsp.Net with the same user id and password that I have in my web.config file but my web.config throws an error.

Comment: And your sure the connection problem is on your "Product" connection string, not your "EmailmeContext" connection? Sorry I cannot be more help. I am not familiar with SmarterASP. They have 24/7 chat support. I would ask them what you're doing wrong.

Comment: BTW, I don't think SQL Auth allows "\" in the user name. This would usually lead me to believe IFC is the domain 'IFC\WIN5062$' which means it is using NT Auth. If your sure it is the "Product" connection that is causing the error, try adding `Integrated Security=False` to it.

Comment: I belive that error is throw by the ProducteEntities connection where the are "Integrated Security=True".

Answer (score 4):

Just turn `Integrated Security=True` to `False` and it will work, it worked for me when I had similar problem.